# Run a PHP code to get a value from a database according to a value of a text element

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

All I;m building a web based system. Here I was thinking whether I can get Name according to the number I enter in a text box. What I've tried is as follows. I know it's not working. Will there be another workaround for that? Please help...

html code is

```
    Item No:<input name="iNo" type="text" id="iNo" size="40" maxlength="6" onblur="namesrch()">
    Item Name:<input name="na" type="text" id="na" size="40" maxlength="40"  disabled>
```

Here's my javascript

```
function namesrch(){
            iNumber = document.getElementById('iNo').value;
            document.getElementById('na').value="<?php $SQL="SELECT iName FROM item Where iNo='iNumber'" ; $run=mySQL_Query($SQL,$con) or die ("SQL error"); while($rec=mySQL_fetch_array($run)){echo $rec{'iName'}}?>";
        }
```

Hope you can understand what I'm trying to do. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe think about putting your code on several lines instead of just one long one.

Comment: You cannot mix javascript and php like that.  You need to make an AJAX call with the value from the input, passing it to the server, which runs the PHP to request the information, and returns it to the javascript.

Comment: Remember how things work: PHP runs on the server at the time you request the page initially. It doesn't have access to dynamically changing Javascript values on the client.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a client side language, where as PHP is a server side language. You can't run PHP inside JavaScript like that. What you need is [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Here is a quick example:

**Javascript**

```
$('#iNo').on('update', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: { no: $(this).val() }
        success: function(name) {
            $('#na').val(name);
        }
    });
});
```

**Ajax.php**

```
$dbConn = new MySqli($host, $username, $passwd, $dbName);
$no= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "no", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$query = "SELECT iName FROM item WHERE iNo = $no";
$result = $dbConn->query($query);
$name = '';
if($dbConn->errno) {
    //An error occurred
} elseif($result->num_rows) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $name = $row['iNo'];
    $result->free();
}

echo $name;
```

You will notice I used [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), rather than MySQL. MySQL is depreciated and should no longer be used. It is worth your time learning to use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix php and js. Assuming you want all the code in one file:

filename.php (Not tested)

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['iNumber'])) {

        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database_name");

        // You need to check for sql injection here

        $SQL = "SELECT iName FROM item Where iNo = '".$_GET['iNumber']."'' LIMIT 1"; 

        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

        echo json_encode(array('iName' => $row['iName']));

        exit();
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    Item No:<input name="iNo" type="text" id="iNo" size="40" maxlength="6" onblur="namesrch()">
    Item Name:<input name="na" type="text" id="na" size="40" maxlength="40"  disabled>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function namesrch() {
            iNumber = document.getElementById('iNo').value;

            $.getJSON('filename.php?iNumber='+iNumber, function(response) {
                $('#na').value(response.name);
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```